# Prism - composite view with single view model spanning on two regions

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I've search over SO but it seems I can't find anything no this.

I have a thing like this:

[image]

Where view A is a list of files, and view B navigates to a different folder (breadcrumb control). View B also features some functionality if view A has some items selected (like select all, delete) etc. So basically they are related and should be one view.

What I need is:

- either having one view span over two regions
- or having two views, but with one view model
- having navigation work, so if view A is navigated, view B is navigated too

I'm going to have more such situations over the whole app, so I'm looking for some common infrastructure for this to work. Is that possible in Prism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish what you want.  Here is a PluralSight course showing you how to load dependent views in one region base on the what's being navigated to in another region using a custom region behavior.

https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-problems-solutions

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: The link provides the full walk through, explanation, and sample code. No need to regurgitate what's already there.

Comment: Added the essential part which is to use a custom region behavior.

Comment: Actually this helps me a lot, as I happened to have Pluralsight subscription at this point. I'll see if it helped and get back here.

Comment: It helped, I developed a RegionBahoviour which suits for my needs, allows for sharing same VM - things work. I know the answer is not perfect because Pluralsight is not free, but I mark this as accepter answer because it did help - thanks a lot.